# Error when trying to create a new table in SQL Server using C++

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server

This is a function that creates a connection to SQL Server and attempts to create a new table..

I tried everything I could think of and now I am clueless.  The connection to the server works fine, but the msg "could not create a new table" always appears. (I already tried to look in other Stack Overflow posts about the topic).

It gives me this error:

[image]

This is a picture of my main and errors it shows that a simple query works:

[image]

```
   void DB::runQuery(string SQLQuery)
{


    SQLCHAR retConString[1024]; // Conection string
    switch (SQLDriverConnect(SQLConnectionHandle, NULL, (SQLCHAR*)"DRIVER={SQL Server}; SERVER=localhost, 1433; DATABASE=myDB; UID=myID; PWD=1234;", SQL_NTS, retConString, 1024, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT)) {
        // Establishes connections to a driver and a data source
    case SQL_SUCCESS:
        break;
    case SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO:
        break;
    case SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND:
        showSQLError(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, SQLConnectionHandle);
        retCode = -1;
        break;
    case SQL_INVALID_HANDLE:
        showSQLError(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, SQLConnectionHandle);
        retCode = -1;
        break;
    case SQL_ERROR:
        showSQLError(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, SQLConnectionHandle);
        retCode = -1;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    if (retCode == -1)
        print("An error occurred");

    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, SQLConnectionHandle, &SQLStatementHandle))
        // Allocates the statement
        print("could not allocate the statement");

    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecDirect(SQLStatementHandle, (SQLCHAR*)SQLQuery.c_str(), SQL_NTS)) {
        // Executes a preparable statement
        showSQLError(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, SQLStatementHandle);
        print("could not execute the statement");
    }
    else {
        char name[256];
        int age;
        while (SQLFetch(SQLStatementHandle) == SQL_SUCCESS) {
            // Fetches the next rowset of data from the result
            SQLGetData(SQLStatementHandle, 1, SQL_C_DEFAULT, &name, sizeof(name), NULL);
            SQLGetData(SQLStatementHandle, 2, SQL_C_DEFAULT, &age, sizeof(age), NULL);
            // Retrieves data for a single column in the result set
            cout << name << " " << age << endl;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: The error message in yoru screenshots says exactly what the problem is.  You don't have permissions to create tables in the database, which is a separate permission from being able to read data from them.  You will either need to talk to your dba / system administrator and get permissions or, if you can, grant the permissions to the login you are using to connect to the database.

Comment: thank you! it works now (:
i spend whole day on this but at the end i just needed to grant premession like you said

Comment: Great!  Glad you got it working :)